# \tabularx with usage of variables: How to add an additional column?

Tags: equations, environments, tabularx, legend, variable

**What happened?**

I built a `tabularx`-environment to simplify the usage of my legends below equations. This is a pretty common table with two columns.

---

**Minimum working example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

    \newenvironment{legend*}{
        \begingroup
            \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}\hspace{1.5em}{}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
            {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
            \par
        \endgroup
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{legend*}
        P_{ges} & Power [unit] \\
        A_{ges} & Area [unit] \\
        V_{ges} & Volume [unit]
    \end{legend*}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: You can see the two columns: Left column is the name of the variable, right column is the description and the relating unit.]

---

**The question:**

In the text itself, I only have to recall this environment via `\begin{environment}` and feed the input into the table. However, I want to add an additional column to the right side for separating the units from the previous description. How can I get that?

---

**It should then look like that:**

```
\begin{legend*}
    P_{ges} & Power & [unit] \\
    A_{ges} & Area & [unit] \\
    V_{ges} & Volume & [unit]
\end{legend*}
```

---

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you have specified a 2-column table `\tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}\hspace{1.5em}{}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`  so if you want the third column to be (say) left aligned, just add an `l`, so:  `\tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}\hspace{1.5em}{}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X l }`

Comment: note the `$` do not signify variables but just math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @ David Carlisle!

```
\tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}\hspace{1.5em}{}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X l }
```

... brought the solution!